# MySQL innoDB is brutally slow with large data count - using index

Tags: mysql

Trying to figure out what exactly is slowing down the query.

The query itself looks similar to this:

```
SELECT name 
FROM players USE INDEX(players_name_status_IDX) 
WHERE name = 'test' AND status = 1
```

Searching for the same name (test) with about 150k entries inside the table, it takes me about 60ms. Now I am up to almost half a million (~490k) entries and the time of execution of the exact same query takes me about roughly 200ms.

Please note, that i am looking for a name, that is not existing on purpose, so the query searches the whole dataset.

Comment: Did you check the load of operating system during these selects?

Comment: The load is not existing at all. I am the only one who's operating the server right now. I executed those two queries on the separate databases in a few seconds multiple times.

Comment: Provide complete CREATE TABLE script and complete EXPLAIN output.